# Label Tag value not getting populated

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code. I want to take input from a user and display the twice of 
that number on the page. I am using `document.getElementById("output").value=value;` so that the label tag with id output value is changed or in other words it becomes like 
10 when user has entered 5 in the input box but I cannot see this value 10. What could be going wrong here?
Separately I am sure it's not the best way to design this kind of thing. If anyone could 
 share insights on how to write a better code, it would be great.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="input">Enter number :</label>
    <input id="text" type="text"></input><br><br>
     
    <input id="button" type="submit"></input><br>
    <label id="output"></label>
<script>
    let inputButton = document.getElementById("button");
    inputButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        let value = parseInt(document.getElementById("text").value);
        value=value*2;
        document.getElementById("output").value=value;
    });
   
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: labels do not have value, inputs do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<label>` doesn't have value, instead use `textContent` like:

```js
let inputButton = document.getElementById("button");
inputButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let value = parseInt(document.getElementById("text").value);
  value = value * 2;
  document.getElementById("output").textContent = value;
});
```

```html
<label for="input">Enter number :</label>
<input id="text" type="text"><br><br>

<input id="button" type="submit"><br>
<label id="output"></label>
```

Reference:

- [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)
- [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)
- [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

---

PS: I also linked the `inputs` link to you because I saw you were trying to close them, read that too well

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, I gave id to elements each time I wanted to access them, as you may have noticed above. Is that a reasonable approach? Could there be a better design for this?

Comment: it is one of the many possible ways, it always depends on the situation. If you use "id" always remember that it must be unique .

Comment: @daniel can you approve my question?